# Meaning of: Play at any time

Tags: monopoly-empire

In the **Monopoly Empire** game, some of the **Empire** cards say

> Play at any time.

I'd like to understand the exact meaning of this rule.

- Does it mean at any time during my turn and/or I am involved in someone else's turn?
- Or does it mean at any time even during other player's turn who does nothing involving me?

Other **Empire** cards specify they are to be played during one's turn:

> Play at any time on your turn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Play at any time" means exactly that. Whenever the player wants to do it, they can.

"Play at any time during your turn" restricts the prior freedom in one way - it must be the turn of the person playing the card.

No other conditions are relevant.